# Reading JSON in html

Tags: javascript, html, json

what I'm trying to do should be pretty simple but somehow  I just don't get it work?

so I have the following JSON file  `jsonFile.json` :

```
{
    "level1":"elemet1",
    "level2":"element2",
    "level3":{
        "testing":"element3"
    }
}
```

And I want to access the data in it, using and HTML page like this one `index.html`:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>

    <title>JSON Example</title>

</head>
<body>

    <div id="data1">Level 1 value :  </div>    
    <div id="data2">Level 2 value :  </div> 
    <div id="data3">Level 3 value :  </div> 





    <script>
        function loadJSON(callback) {   

        var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
        xobj.open('GET', 'jsonFile.json', true); // Replace 'my_data' with the path to your file
        xobj.onreadystatechange = function () {
              if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200") {
                // Required use of an anonymous callback as .open will NOT return a value but simply returns undefined in asynchronous mode
                callback(xobj.responseText);
              }
        };
        xobj.send(null);  
        }

        function init() {

         loadJSON(function(response) {
          // Parse JSON string into object
            var actual_JSON = JSON.parse(response); 

            for (var key in actual_JSON) {
                var innerkey = actual_JSON[key];
                for (var inner in innerkey) {
                     document.getElementById('data1').innerHTML += 'Level 1 value'+innerkey[inner]['level1']+'<br>';
                     document.getElementById('data2').innerHTML += 'Level 2 value: '+innerkey[inner]['level2']+'<br>';
                     document.getElementById('data2').innerHTML += 'Level 3 value: '+innerkey[inner]['level3']+'<br>';
                }   
            }   
         }); 
        }
        init();
        </script>

</body>
</html>
```

so calling the "index.html" from the browser directly delivers the following error :

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/Users/Engine/Documents/JSON_TEST/jsonFile.json' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, brave, https.
loadJSON @ index.html:31
```

to solve it I'm using now a `node.js`server `app.js` :

```
    var http = require('http');
var fs =require('fs');


var server = http.createServer(function(req,res){
    console.log('request was made : '+req.url);
    res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type':'text/html'});
    var myReadStream  = fs.createReadStream(__dirname +'/index.html','utf8');
    myReadStream.pipe(res);
});

server.listen('3000','127.0.0.1');

console.log('listening to 3000');
```

So now calling the `app.js` using :

```
node app.js
```

and calling  the address : 127.0.0.1:3000

here  is the error I get:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at (index):38
at XMLHttpRequest.xobj.onreadystatechange ((index):28)
```

So again, I guess it should be simple, but I just don't what I'm missing here! 
thanks in advance for any help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are always returning `index.html` regardless the URL requested by the user. Try opening `http://localhost:3000/jsonFile.json` in your browser: you will see the content of the HTML file, not the expected json.

Let me use your own code to prove my point:

```
var server = http.createServer(function(req,res){
    console.log('request was made : '+req.url);
    var myReadStream;

    // If the user requests the json file...
    if (req.url.endsWith('jsonFile.json')) {
        // ...get the json file, NOT the index.html
        myReadStream  = fs.createReadStream(__dirname +'/jsonFile.json', 'utf8');
    } else {
        myReadStream  = fs.createReadStream(__dirname +'/index.html', 'utf8');
    }
    res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type':'text/html'});
    myReadStream.pipe(res);
});
```

There are better ways to create this server. Take a look at [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server).

After fixing this, you will have to take a look at your javascript loop, but the variable `actual_JSON` will have the content of the JSON file.

Comment: still don't get how  to do it properly, but at the least the server is working now ! thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

use library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/load-json-file

```
case '/credential': {
            const credential = await loadJsonFile("./credential.json");
            response.end(JSON.stringify(credential, null, 3));
            break;
        }
```

[image]